# Entry text does not shown in Xamarin.Forms UWP

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a following structure of code in Xamarin application.

```
<StackLayout>

        <Entry Text="XYZ"/>

        <ScrollView>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
                <Grid>

                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Black"/>

                    <Entry Grid.Row="1" Text="ABCD" VerticalOptions="Center"/>

                    <BoxView Grid.Row="2" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Aqua"/>

                    <BoxView Grid.Row="3" HeightRequest="1" BackgroundColor="Blue"/>

                    <Label Grid.Row="4" Text="12" TextColor="Red" VerticalOptions="Start"/>

                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </StackLayout>
```

Entry text "ABCD" does not shown in UWP but it's working fine in android.

Please find the screenshot
[image]

Comment: Hi , if `Entry` with word `XYZ` shows , then `ABCD` will also shows . Have a check whether there is difference with Xamarin Android .

Answer (score 1):

See: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/10137

Try removing the outer ScrollView.
Fixes it for me (but long forms are not possible without redesign UX).